# coefficient plot bucket in categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

using ggplot2, I would like to structure the graphic by bucketing the labels A to J in categories. E.g. A, B, C would be called "Category 1", D, E, F would be called "Category 2", and G, H, I, J would be called "Category 3". Similar as was done in this graphic:

[image]

Below my current code. How can I accomplish this using ggplot2? Thank you!

```
  plotdata <- structure(
  list(term = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
    estimate = c(-0.033882004, 0.001508041,
      0.122957935,-0.033882004,
      0.001508041,
      -0.033882004,
      0.001508041,
      0.122957935,-0.033882004,
      0.001508041
    ),
    ymin = c(
      -0.13278953,
      -0.007547426,
      0.025116265,
      -0.13278953,
      -0.007547426,
      -0.13278953,
      -0.007547426,
      0.025116265,
      -0.13278953,
      -0.007547426
    ),
    ymax = c(
      0.065025521,
      0.010563508,
      0.220799605,
      0.065025521,
      0.010563508,
      0.065025521,
      0.010563508,
      0.220799605,
      0.065025521,
      0.010563508
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(
      term = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                         "collector")),
      estimate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                             "collector")),
      ymin = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                         "collector")),
      ymax = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                         "collector"))
    ),
    default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                          "collector")),
    delim = ","
  ), class = "col_spec"),
  class = c("spec_tbl_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
        
    
    # Libraries
            library(dplyr)
            library(broom)
            library(ggplot2)
           
         
            
            # Make plot
            p <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(x=term, y=estimate)) + 
              geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="#c10534", size=0.5) +  # Line at 0
              geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), size=0.5, color="#1a476f", shape=1, stroke = 1) +  # Ranges for each coefficient
              labs(x="", y="Coefficient Estimate", title="") +  # Labels
              coord_flip() +  # Rotate the plot
              theme_classic() +
              theme(text=element_text(size=13), axis.text.y=element_text(size=13), axis.text.x=element_text(size=13))
            p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with facets:

```r
plotdata %>%
  mutate(category = rep(paste('Category', 1:3), times = c(3, 3, 4))) %>%
  mutate(term = factor(term, levels = rev(term))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = term, y = estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="#c10534", size = 0.5) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), size = 0.5, color = "#1a476f", 
                  shape = 1, stroke = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Coefficient Estimate") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.4, 0.1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(category~., switch = 'y', scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = 'bold'),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

To have the labels horizontal, you could do something like:

```r
plotdata %>%
  mutate(category = rep(paste('Category', 1:3), times = c(3, 3, 4))) %>%
  mutate(term = factor(term, levels = rev(term))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = term, y = estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="#c10534", size = 0.5) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), size = 0.5, color = "#1a476f", 
                  shape = 1, stroke = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Coefficient Estimate") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.4, 0.1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(category~., switch = 'y', scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = 'bold', angle = 0, vjust = 1),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would it also be possible to have the categories horizontally, as in the example graphic that I posted above?

Comment: @Neicooo see my update

Comment: This is perfect! One last question, how do I label the categories with particular names. E.g. Category 1 = Environment, Category 2 = Cities, Category = Weather?

Comment: @Neicooo the labels for each category are created in the second line of the code above. Effectively, you just create a column that assigns each row of your data frame a label that will become its grouping category. Instead of `paste("Category", 1:3)` you might have`c("Environment", "Cities", "Weather")`

Comment: Great, and how can I make them (the labels) align left instead of right?

Comment: Sorry, which labels are aligned right?

Comment: Environment, Cities, Weather - they're on the left side, but the text is aligned to the left

Comment: You could try playing with `vjust` and `hjust` inside the `element_text` in the second last line to change the position of this text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248002/discussion-between-neicooo-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: @Neicoo I'd prefer not to go into chat. Perhaps you can post another question showing exactly what you are trying to achieve using your real labels? It's very difficult to answer supplementary questions via comments, but I'm sure it will be quicker and easier if you show what you are looking for with a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73699737/tidy-up-coefficient-plot