# Tidy up coefficient plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the below coefficient plot, I would like to decrease the white space under "Roads" and "Timing" as highlighted in red:
[image]

How can I make this look tidier? Below is my current code, using ggplot2:

```
plotdata <- structure(
  list(
    term = c("Category 1_a","Category 1_b","Category 1_c","Category 1_d","Category 2",
      "Category 3_a","Category 3_b"),
    estimate = c(-0.033882004,0.001508041,0.122957935,-0.033882004,0.001508041,-0.033882004,0.001508041),
    ymin = c(
      -0.13278953,-0.007547426,0.025116265,-0.13278953,-0.007547426,-0.13278953,-0.007547426), ymax = c(0.065025521,0.010563508,0.220799605,0.065025521,0.010563508,0.065025521,0.010563508)
  ), row.names = c(NA,-7L),
  spec = structure(list(cols = list(
      term = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                         "collector")),
      estimate = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                             "collector")),
      ymin = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                         "collector")),
      ymax = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                         "collector"))
    ),
    default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                          "collector")),
    delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),class = c("spec_tbl_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

# Plot
plotdata %>%
  mutate(category = rep(c("Pollution", "Roads", "Timing"), times = c(4, 1, 2))) %>%
  mutate(term = factor(term, levels = rev(term))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = term, y = estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="black", size = 0.5, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), size = 0.5, 
                  fill="#0202fe", color="#b5b5b5", shape=21, stroke = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Coefficient Estimate") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.4, 0.1)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(category~., switch = 'y', scales = 'free_y') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = 'bold', angle = 0, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `space` argument of `facet_grid`. Setting `space="free_y"` will set the panel size according to the "proportional to the length of the y scale", i.e. the number of categories:

Note: I also dropped the `scale_x_discrete`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

# Plot
plotdata %>%
  mutate(category = rep(c("Pollution", "Roads", "Timing"), times = c(4, 1, 2))) %>%
  mutate(term = factor(term, levels = rev(term))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = term, y = estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="black", size = 0.5, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), size = 0.5, 
                  fill="#0202fe", color="#b5b5b5", shape=21, stroke = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Coefficient Estimate") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(category~., switch = 'y', scales = 'free_y', space = "free_y") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(face = 'bold', angle = 0, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks already promising. @stefan why is though the space below "Pollution" different than the one under "Roads" and "Timing"?

Comment: Yeah. I have just made an edit, i.e. I dropped `scale_x_discrete`. The issue is that you expanded the "x" ,i.e. y scale multiplicative by ".4" which works fine with fixed panel sizes but not when we free the space. If it is needed then use an additive expansion.

Comment: Thank you @stefan. Is there also a way to add a frame around the entire panel of the graph? When I use "panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=0.5)" it draws a panel around each section (pollution, roads, timing).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any option or any extension package to achieve that. But it would be a nice feature if one could set the borders in geom_rect separately. Of course, if you are inclined to dig deeper into grid graphics and in manipulating the gtable than I would guess that this could be achieved. I would suggest to ask a new question on that. There are some guys on SO which are really good on that and which have much better knowledge of these topics and the ggplot internals than me.